# Sampling from a Gaussian mixture (toy example ) using MALA

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, stochastic-processes, markov-process, differential-equations, langevin-diffusion

Say I want to sample from a Gaussian mixture $$\pi=\sum_{i=1}^3w_i\mathcal N(x_i,\sigma_i^2I_2)\tag1$$ where he support of the 3 distributions are "effectively separated"; e.g.

- $w_1=.1$, $x_1=(-22, -22)$, $\sigma_1=3$
- $w_2=.3$, $x_2=(-1,-1)$, $\sigma_2=.2$,
- $w_3=.6$, $x_3=(15,15)$, $\sigma_3=1$

on the domain $[a,b]^2$ with $a=-30$ and $b=20$. This is depicted [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=plot+Divide%5B0.1%2C2*pi*Power%5B3%2C2%5D%5D*exp%5C%2840%29-Divide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29x%2B22%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5B%5C%2840%29y%2B22%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2C2*Power%5B3%2C2%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%2BDivide%5B0.3%2C2*pi*Power%5B0.2%2C2%5D%5D*exp%5C%2840%29-Divide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29x%2B1%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5B%5C%2840%29y%2B1%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2C2*Power%5B0.2%2C2%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%2BDivide%5B0.6%2C2*pi%5D*exp%5C%2840%29-Divide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29x-15%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5B%5C%2840%29y-15%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29+from+x%3D-30+to+20+and+y%3D-30+to+20):

I would like to a sampler which locally explores the state space according to the Langevin dynamics $${\rm d}X_t=\frac{\sigma^2}2\nabla\ln p(X_t){\rm d}t+\sigma W_t\tag2,$$ where $p$ is the density of $(1)$ and $\sigma=.01$ or something like that.

Now, there are several problems with this:

1. When we start at some $x_0$ for which $p(x_0)\approx0$, then $\nabla\ln p(x_0)$ will be huge (in magnitude) or even undefined.
2. Even when $p$ is nicer: When $\sigma=.01$, it seems like that the noise $\sigma W_t$ will always have greater impact on the next move than the drift $\frac{\sigma^2}2\nabla\ln p(X_t)$ (since when $\sigma<1$, then $\sigma^2\ll1$). And beyond that: How do we choose $\sigma$ appropriately? Depending on $p$, a specific choice of $\sigma$ might be totally unfeasible (think about even spikier Gaussians centered around $0$; then anything with variance $>1$ would make no sense, since each move would end in a point with (almost) vanishing density).

What can we do here? Or what is usually done in practice?

*Disclaimer*: The Gaussian mixture target is simply a toy example highlighting one of the issues I'm encountering in my actual application. So, a more general advice (i.e. not something special which only works for the Gaussian mixture) would be nice.

Having said that: Note that there is no easy way for me to detect the modes of the distribution beforehand (and start local dynamics at each mode or something like that).

What might help though: I don't necessarily need to sample from the specific distribution $\pi$, but only from a distribution which is large wherever $\pi$ is large (think about some kind of importance sampling here). I first thought about replacing $p$ by $e^p$, but is that a good idea?